How do I fix this error? I've tried everything from uninstalling and this doesn't seem to work
enter image description hereI've installed torch in the normal command prompt and also in the CLI of VS Code. Still the problem persists.
I've tried everything from running on a virtual environment to re-installing the entire stack. From uninstalling python to visual code, I've tried everything
Exception has occurred: OSError
[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\kalya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\Transformer\train.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\kalya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.


what problem exactly?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Title: OSError [WinError 126] running Python script in VS Code: Unable to load module
Encountering OSError [WinError 126] while executing Python script in VS Code. Error occurs at import torch statement:
arduino
Copy code
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found.
Error loading "C:\Users\kalya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\Transformer\train.py", line 1, in import torch

similar question here

For anyone still experiencing this one, I found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78794748/10549172
